# How to compute number of dichotomies/growth function value?

Tags: machine-learning, growth-model, vc-dimension

I am studying the book 'learning from data' by Mostafa. I understand that the number of dichotomies for positive rays on the number line is $N+1$ (ie if you have one point, $x$, on the number line, you have the ray from $0$ to $\infty$ and the ray from $x$ to $\infty$ for example).

What I am wondering, though, is what would be the number of dichotomies for positive and negative rays (ie negative rays in $(-\infty,0]$ are $+1$ and positive rays in $[0, \infty)$ are $+1$)? Would you just add the separate dichotomies yielding $(N+1)+(N+1)$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dichotomy"? What is $N$?

Comment: Dichotomies := number of distinct ways to divide the data.
N := number of data points along the number line

Comment: What data? Also, is a "positive ray" a ray that points in the positive direction or a ray that consists entirely of positive numbers (or both)?

Comment: Data consists of the points (any number of them) that you choose along the number line. 
If my data consists of the number 5 on the number line, then I have two positive rays (one from 0 to infinity and one from 5 to infinity, thus I have N+1=2 positive rays). 
Is that clear?

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to having an interval that is negative, i.e. gives a negative label to the points in the interval.

For intervals the growth function is $\binom{n+1}{2} + 1$. This is because the problem is equivalent to trying to choose 2 sections between the $n+1$ possible sections, $+1$ for the case where you choose the same section twice, i.e. there is no interval.